# Getting error when i use pip install baselines

Tags: python, macos, pycharm

conf:mac catalina,MacBook Pro (13-inch, 2019, Two Thunderbolt 3 ports),pycharm.

the error:

```
ERROR: Failed building wheel for mpi4py
  Building wheel for zmq (setup.py) ... done
  Created wheel for zmq: filename=zmq-0.0.0-py3-none-any.whl size=1264 sha256=be7f6ab763266c2291f5ca7998e3ad24e48a4e85c04a2aa09a7fd5531823ae5b
  Stored in directory: /Users/mac/Library/Caches/pip/wheels/4d/41/3a/bfd4dafaf1c20a4d08ff78bfcab77fcc4cf98e97c7941ce77a
Successfully built baselines zmq
Failed to build mpi4py
ERROR: Could not build wheels for mpi4py, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

Comment: you can try to create new virtual environment and try to install it there

Comment: @DreadfulWeather it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Try updating pip before installation :

```
pip3 install --upgrade pip
```

Comment: i tried,doesn't work,still the error.

Answer (score 0):

Create new virtualenv clear the pip cache like below and try to install it again.

```
pip cache purge
```

I checked the [documentation](https://mpi4py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/install.html), it also says you need to install MPI implementation